# Как правильно повернуть отцентрированный текст на канвасе?

Tags: text, android, canvas

Есть канвас с размерами экрана устройства.
есть текст (3 строки, длина каждой динамична) с фиксированным размером шрифта.
задача: нужно отцентрировать этот текст на канвасе и повернуть его на 45 градусов против часовой стрелки (как на картинке), не теряя центровки. Слышал, что есть очень простая формула для вычисления координат. Пожалуйста, помогите или найти эту формулу, или посоветовать код для такого случая.

P.S. пожалуйста, не закрывайте вопрос! мне правда нужна ваша помощь![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вот так:

---

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 123, 0));
p.setTextSize((int)textSize);
p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

                int xPos = (c.getWidth() / 2);
            int yPos = (int) ((c.getHeight() / 2) - ((p.descent() + p.ascent()) / 2));

            c.save();
            c.rotate(-45, xPos, yPos);
            c.drawText(text, xPos, yPos - (int)textSize, p);
            c.drawText(text2, xPos, yPos, p);
            c.drawText(text3, xPos, yPos + (int)textSize, p);
            c.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то текст можно рассматривать как прямоугольник.
Тогда решение вашей задачи рассмотрено тут: [Build HTML5 websites Build HTML5 mobile apps](http://www.pvsm.ru/html5-canvas/20808)